# SSH key generation for GIT on Windows 8

Tags: git, ssh, windows-8

I am trying to generate a new SSH key on my windows computer using command prompt.
I have installed Cygwin and added its path to use linux commands through command prompt.

Now ls is listing me the inner folders.
But ssh is still nor working.

On trying to generate SSH key using the command
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email_id"

its giving me a following error.
ssh-keygen is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: check if this link helps http://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key

Comment: Why don't you install git-scm http://git-scm.com/download/win

Answer (score 1):

No need for cygwin: a regular [msysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases) is enough (unzip [`PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20141217.7z`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.5-preview20141217/PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20141217.7z) anywhere you want, add its `bin/` folder to your path and you have `git` *and* ssh including `ssh-keygen`)

Once you have launched its [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat), you can generate your ssh keys.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email_id" -q -P ""
```

(here I don't use a passphrase, for testing purposes, avoiding the ssh-agent management)

`id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` will be generated in `%HOME%/.ssh`.
`HOME` is set by the `git-cmd.bat`, usually in `%USERPROFILE%`.

Answer (score 1):

I am probably one of the only few people still left who might be using Windows 8 for development purposes. However my solution is quite simple if anyone comes looking for this answer like me.

All you need to do is the following:

1. Download Git: https://git-scm.com/downloads
2. Install Git
3. Run Git Bash
4. In the Git Bash terminal type: `ssh-keygen`
5. Enter the location you want the keys to be stored:

> /c/Users/(my_user)/.ssh/(key_file_name)

6. Enter your password and press enter

Your new ssh key pair has been generated.